# filling an array using json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, angularjs

I want to fill my array in the controller but in my database i have id, name, age... how do i fill my array only with names using angular, javascript or Jquery?

i tried this

```
$scope.myarray=[];

function load(callback){  
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'the url',
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        success: function(response) {
            callback.call(this, response.name);
            $scope.myarray.push(response.name);
        }
    });
```

its not filling the $scope.myarray help please.

Comment: are you getting any errors in your javascript console? and your question title is misleading, you are tyring to fill array from json response.

Comment: I dont know if its a typo, a `}` is missing at the end of code.

Comment: i think Patrick Evans is right... still not working

Comment: AngularJS has a really cool thing called `ngResource` . It'll return an array and will _automagically_ fill it for you when the resource returns (in this case your AJAX) See - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2432-Applying-A-Cached-Response-To-An-AngularJS-Resource.htm . (Hint, it's not really magic :))

Comment: if you are using angularjs why don't you use ngResource?

Comment: it is not working also :( i am new to angular so i dont know how to do it properly

Comment: can you post the response JSON?

Comment: check whether your ajax call is going in success method. trying adding error function in your ajax call..

Comment: Have you tried adding `$scope.$apply()` after you change `$scope.myarray`?  If the callback is being called outside of the scope (like by jQuery), then you will need to manually apply it.